# Initialize async data in ViewModel .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

Hope you all guys are doing great.
I am new to MAUI .NET and MVVM pattern, I'm running through something that I don't seem to find an answer to solve my problem, Which is...
For example:

```cs
public BotsViewModel(UiPathService _uiPathService)
{

    Title = "UiPath Bots";
    
    this.uiPathService = _uiPathService;
    
    //This is an async method which loads data on the view attached to the viewmodel
    
    GetTopBotsByLoSAsync();
}
```

I am not having a problem with loading data on initialization but while navigating and searching for better practices, I ran into that initializing data on a constructor is a bad practice and also Async data...
How should i do this the right way, I followed allot of MAUI tutorials and all teachers seem to initialize data with the click of a button, but it doesn't feel the right way to me, I need to have all data in the page after is loaded with no user prompt to get it... so the only way i find to init data is this way I'm currently using, which is calling this async method (This method calls an API which fetch's data for my view)  that is not being awaited in my constructor.
Does anyone know how can I refactor this for better practices?

I need better practices please help haha

Comment: Best practice is to prepare the data before asking for page, so can pass it in as a parameter to constructor. Thus, there is no delay during page construction. A static method can help with this. Have that static build a small class (or struct) to hold the data while preparing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the `.SafeFireAndForget()` extension method found in the [`AsyncAwaitBestPractices` NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices).

It allows you to run an async method without needing to `await` it, while still ensuring best practices are being followed (e.g. you should await every `Task` and the library does this for you under the hood by leveraging one of the few valid use-cases of `async void`).

**Full disclosure**: I'm the author of this library, but it has over a million combined downloads with its companion library, the [`AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM` NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM).

The code is all open-source and you're welcome to copy/paste the source code into your app if you don't want to add a 3rd Party Dependency: https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices

Its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices) also includes a deeper explanation, including videos I've made, on how async/await works and why I created this library.

```cs
using AsyncAwaitBestPractices;

public BotsViewModel(UiPathService _uiPathService)
{

    Title = "UiPath Bots";
    
    this.uiPathService = _uiPathService;
    
    //This is an async method which loads data on the view attached to the viewmodel
    
    GetTopBotsByLoSAsync().SafeFireAndForget();
}
```

Comment: I assume constructor returns BEFORE that method finishes its work? Important to mention that, if true.

Comment: Correct! The async method, `GetTopBotsByLoSAsync()`, will run in the background. Meanwhile the constructor will return while the `GetTopBotsByLoSAsync()`continues running in the background until completion. I assume the author is displaying an "IsLoading" UI to the user while the information is being gathered in the background.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Hi! Thanks for your comment, I have a doubt, will this block UI thread while waiting for data?

Comment: No, `.SafeFireAndForget()` does not block the UI thread

Answer (score 2):

> initializing data on a constructor is a bad practice and also Async data...

To be clear, blocking the UI thread waiting for the data to arrive is a bad practice, just like any other blocking of the UI. Instead, what you need to do is synchronously initialize the UI to a "Loading" state and *start* the asynchronous operation, and then when the data arrives, *update* the UI into a "Ready" state with the new data.

It appears your code is already following that general pattern, but there is a problem with how `GetTopBotsByLoSAsync` is called: any exceptions will be ignored. This is fine if `GetTopBotsByLoSAsync` has a top-level `try`/`catch` that updates the UI into an "Error" state.

Alternatively, you can use a "notify task" type like [this one](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm/blob/master/future/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs) which allows you to use data binding to switch between "Loading", "Ready", and "Error" states. My original article on this type is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding).

Comment: Stephen, thanks for your response, I'll keep an eye on this and I'll let you know if it suits my solution good. Great stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
public BotsViewModel(UiPathService _uiPathService)
{

    Title = "UiPath Bots";
    
    this.uiPathService = _uiPathService;
    
    //This is an async method which loads data on the view attached to the viewmodel
    
    Task.Run(async () => await GetTopBotsByLoSAsync());
//dont block UI thread, but I think this option is not best practices
}
```